# Circle follow cursor after hover on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to remake hover like on this website:

https://www.samsaraubud.com/

When you hover over a button (and only button. I don't want circle over whole website), a circle appers around cursor. I tried so many solutions from codepen after typing "mouse follow" but nothing works.

I have button like this:

https://codepen.io/Aventadorrre/pen/mdyPJbv

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Button</a>
```

and how to make circle around mouse (following mouse) when i hover button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a `radial-gradient` as background that you make `fixed` then simply adjust the position based on the cursor

```js
var h =document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  /* 15 = background-size/2 */
  h.style.setProperty('background-position',(e.clientX - 15)+'px '+(e.clientY - 15)+'px');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

a.cursor {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, 
     transparent calc(100% - 3px),
     red calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 1px),
     transparent 100%) 
     fixed /* Fixed to the screen*/ 
     no-repeat; /* Don't repeat*/

  background-size:30px 30px; /* Control the size of the circle */
  
}
```

```html
<a class="cursor" href="#">Button</a>
```

If you want the circle above the text consider pseudo element and the same trick:

```js
var h =document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  h.style.setProperty('background-position',(e.clientX - 15)+'px '+(e.clientY - 15)+'px');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

a.cursor {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background-size:0 0; 
  position:relative;
}
a.cursor::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, 
     blue  calc(100% - 1px),
     transparent 100%) 
     fixed /* Fixed to the screen*/ 
     no-repeat; /* Don't repeat*/
  background-size:30px 30px;
  background-position:inherit;
}
```

```html
<a class="cursor" href="#">Button</a>
```

Comment: Yes! That's what i'm looking for. But how can I make this circle bigger? When i'm resizing bg-size and radial-gradient, it's no in center of the cursor

Comment: @MateuszM you need to also adjust the JS code, you can see I am using 15 which is half the background-size to make it in the center

Comment: Is there any way to make this like this: https://codepen.io/Aventadorrre/pen/rNaeWqd ? I mean, with your example circle is cut off by border. In this example (from link above) circle is still full until you leave the mouse from button

Comment: @MateuszM you can try like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ebro07th/

Comment: Hey, I made my circle bigger and it's still cuting circle near tu button (when you have cursor near to edge). Is it posibble to fix? Here is edited demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cyoe0rnj/

Comment: @MateuszM in the pseudo element I am using -20px in all the direction, increase that value, it needs to be at least equal to circle radius

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

It shows full circle even on the boundaries of the button

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".button")
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle")

btn.onmouseenter = function() {
  circle.classList.add("in")
}


btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const {
    top,
    left,
    width,
    height
  } = btn.getBoundingClientRect()
  const {
    clientY,
    clientX
  } = e
  if (clientX < left || clientY < top || clientX > left + width || clientY > top + height) {
    circle.classList.remove("in")
  }
  circle.style.top = `${clientY - top}px`
  circle.style.left = `${clientX - left}px`
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  padding: 40px 80px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.circle.in {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">
  Button
  <span class="circle"></span>
</a>
```

---

**old answer**
The answer is extension of the answer by @Temani Afif.

The listener for mousemove is added on the button itself instead of the body, which would result in performance improvement since the cb is only called when you are hovering over the button.

```js
var h = document.querySelector(".cursor");

h.onmousemove = function(e) {
  /* 15 = background-size/2 */
  h.style.setProperty(
    "background-position",
    e.clientX - 15 + "px " + (e.clientY - 15) + "px"
  );
};
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

a.cursor {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background: radial-gradient( farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - 3px), red calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 1px), transparent 100%) fixed/* Fixed to the screen*/
  no-repeat;
  /* Don't repeat*/
  background-size: 0px 0px;
  /* by default, circle is of 0px */
}

a.cursor:hover {
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  /* Control the size of the circle */
}
```

```html
<a class="cursor" href="#">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `mousemove` event. Catch the event and set the location of cirlce while the mouse moves.

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
  document.getElementById("circle").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("circle").style.left = e.offsetX + "px";
  document.getElementById("circle").style.top = e.offsetY + "px"; 
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

#circle{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Button</a>

<span id="circle"></span>
```

Comment: Yep, but it works over whole website and i want circle to appear only when i hover button and only in its area