# Make cursor with circle only on hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Hi to all I just wonder if there is possibilities to do same effect as on this link [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si8OT.png) but to show circle beside mouse pointer only when hove something.

like this: [image]

'''https://codepen.io/gmrchk/pen/pQobKL'''

It is something more like this below but need to be applied to any link.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".button")
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle")

btn.onmouseenter = function() {
  circle.classList.add("in")
}


btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const {
    top,
    left,
    width,
    height
  } = btn.getBoundingClientRect()
  const {
    clientY,
    clientX
  } = e
  if (clientX < left || clientY < top || clientX > left + width || clientY > top + height) {
    circle.classList.remove("in")
  }
  circle.style.top = `${clientY - top}px`
  circle.style.left = `${clientX - left}px`
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  padding: 40px 80px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.circle.in {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">
  Button
  <span class="circle"></span>
</a>
```

Just use code I found closely to what I need here: [Circle follow cursor after hover on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268051/circle-follow-cursor-after-hover-on-button)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: It is possible! You can in fact just use the css attribute, `cursor: url(...)` [see more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: Thats not what I meant, when you use that: `cursor: url` cursor became image, but I need image beside cursor pointer, only on hover...

Comment: @DraganPetrovicFSD, you can make an image that is a cursor with an image beside it, only on hover !

Answer (score 3):

You need a bit of JavaScript which will change the position of a circle when the mouse moves over the text, and makes the circle invisible when the mouse is not over the text.

Here's a simple snippet. Obviously you will want to alter the various dimensions to suit your particular requirements.

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
const hoverDiv = document.querySelector('.hoverDiv');
hoverDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  circle.style.display = 'block';
  circle.style.left = e.clientX - 48 + 'px';
  circle.style.top = e.clientY - 48 + 'px';
});
hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
  circle.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hoverDiv {
  display: : inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.circle {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="hoverDiv">Here is some text to hover</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @A Haworth , that is exactly I want to achieve but probably I should use jQuery **append** to inject whenever I need on website `$( ".some-class" ).append( "<div class="circle"></div>" );` and also **addClass** to add `$( ".some-class" ).addClass( "hoverDiv" );` something like that is only option I can see. Is there any alternative options cause there will be mouse effect on all links I have on website like: images, text href and buttons, or Stretched links? Also I wonder is there any simplest solution to be done as default mouse pointer behavior on any link on website?

Comment: I’m not quite understanding how the elements which have this special cursor are chosen. Are you saying they will have a special class and that’s how we find them? Incidentally I can’t see the point in using jquery rather than pure JS..

Comment: It is a dynamic site where it is necessary to define such mouse behavior by default on every link that the user or client adds without having to know coding.